A result concerning heights in an arbitrary triangle
I am trying to understand if the following claim is true or false (probably true?).
The claim says that each of the three heights $\{AA_1,BB_1,CC_1\}$ bisects the relevant angle of the blue triangle.
I have tried to denote all the relevant angles by $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i$,
$1 \leq i \leq 2$, so $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, $\beta=\beta_1+\beta_2$, $\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2$,
but this does not help,
I only get that the sum of those six angles is $180^{\circ}$.
Thank you very much!
Here is my answer thanks to the hint in the comments:


Are you familiar with cyclic quadrilaterals and its properties?

Truly, I am not sure I remember that now. Could you please hint more elaborately?

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cyclic_quadrilateral

If $H$ denotes the orthocenter, then $HA_1BC_1$ is cyclic, so $\angle HA_1C_1 = \angle HBC_1$

Thank you for the hint. I will try to solve this and will comment again soon. Thank you!

I have now succeeded, and will send the drawing. Thank you very much for your help!

Another way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FE0Bkhmsg8
